SQL Server in Azure VM - cannot disable/stop Automated Patching event logs
We have several SQL Servers on VM in Azure - Server 2016 with SQL 2017.
I have disabled in the Azure Portal the SQL Server Automated Parching, BUT i keep getting every 30 seconds events in the system application logs by Microsoft SQL Server Automated Patching with Event ID 55513.
Here is an full XML event:
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft SQL Server Automated Patching" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">55513</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-12-20T19:28:42.491213400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>62990623</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>*REDACTED*</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>[Information] AutomaterPatchingWsusRetrieveError: [WSUS status retrieve failed] Failed with exception: The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it. (0x80070422)</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>

The VMs were created with enableAutomaticUpdates=true which means i cannot set the Windows Update in the Azure Update Manager to Manual updates , but there is no policy set and no updates are set for the Azure Update Manager. Its currently set to Customer managed schedule. Periodic Assesment is also disabled, there is no Hotpatch available. Additionally, the Windows Update service on the OS is disabled.
The question is, why do i keep getting logs about this, despite having the SQL Server automated patching disabled?
